# Importing Bootstrap css overrides all react css

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I found a nice template for a profile page but it was using bootstrap. So I found that I can import the bootstrap styles using:

```
import  'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

However, this overrides all the other CSS that I use throughout the app.
Any way I can use the bootstrap CSS in that page only?

Comment: Can't see the rest of your css imports but you need bootstrap first so it doesn't override all other styles, but can then be overriden (as per the global cascade for CSS).

Comment: Improting it before App.css does not work either

Comment: Call the bootstrap css only to that page.

Comment: I am. When I call it in that page it still overrides the other styles